# Selenium Get relative location of element to page

Tags: c#, selenium, remotewebdriver

I am using Selenium RC with c#. I want to find the relative location of an element with respect to the left top corner of the current page. So if the top left of the screen is at (0, 50) and the element is located at (10, 70), I want to get (10, 20) as the relative location.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by top left of the screen is at (0, 50)?

Comment: those are the (x, y) coordinates, which x is the number of pixels right of the left side of the screen ad y is the number of pixels down from the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

All `WebElement` objects hold a `Location` property
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_Location.htm

However, again, the location may not be relative to the specific point you want.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am not using defaultSelenium, instead I am using selenium RemoteWebDriver. The remote driver does not have this method.

Comment: See if the `Location` property helps, assuming you have a reference to the element you want.

Comment: The location property gives the location of the element from the (0,0) point, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Pretty sure it's relative to the current frame/page, not the monitor. Do you mean that your browser window or a popup window is at a specific position on the screen?

Comment: It is relative to the current page, but I want to find its location with respect to the what I can see in my monitor